# How to make this android layout more 'responsive'?

Tags: android

I have an android layout with some title bar and some input fields, and when I try to input some values, I can do it, but

1. the title bar vanishes
2. If I want to edit the field "Another number" I cannot scroll down to use the `SeekBar` instead.

How can I change the layout to make it

1. Have the title bar (with the text "InputExample") always fixes
2. Have the other content of the screen scrollable (so that I can use the `SeekBar`, for example)?

The layout is here:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:layout_marginBottom = "0dp">


        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/new_cancel"
            android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
            android:columnCount="10"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:useDefaultMargins="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textTitleEdit"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnSpan="10"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:text="My Title"
                android:textSize="32dip"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="You can enter some values"
                android:textSize="16dip"
                android:layout_columnSpan="8"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:id="@+id/textSubTitleEdit"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="0" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Name"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="0"
                />
            <EditText
                android:ems="7"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:id="@+id/new_name"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="1" />




            _____________

            <TextView
                android:text="Label"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_column="0" />



            <EditText
                android:ems="7"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:id="@+id/new_label"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            ______

            <TextView
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:text="Put in a number"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                />

            <EditText
                android:ems="7"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:id="@+id/new_price"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:layout_column="1" />



            <TextView
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:text="Another number"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_row="5" />

            <EditText
                android:ems="7"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:id="@+id/new_offset"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_row="5"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seek_offset"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.SeekBar"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="6"
                android:max="20"/>


            <TextView
                android:text="Comment"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_row="7"
                android:layout_column="0" />



            <EditText
                android:ems="7"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:id="@+id/new_comment"
                android:layout_row="7"
                android:layout_column="1" />

        </GridLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="#aaaaaa"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="#dddddd"
            android:text="Ok"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html#Respond Specifying "adjustResize" is important if your UI includes controls that the user might need to access immediately after or while performing text input.

Comment: Ah interesting. But this comes into the manifest?

Comment: Tried setting `android:windowSoftInputMode` in the manifest did not change the behavior...

Comment: If you're open to changing your layout structure, you can wrap it inside a scrollview or something equivalent so that user can scroll the entire view. Also, yes, that goes in the manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was having some problems with your original layout so I've fixed it up and I think this solution should work. Everything in the preview of the layout has it positioned correctly so hopefully when you use this in the emulator it should work.

I personally prefer using LinearLayouts with weights for the majority of my layouts, I know some others prefer RelativeLayouts.

Essentially you should look to contain the part which you wish to scroll with a layout of some kind and then the ScrollView contains this layout so it can be scrolled. This is why I've removed the title and subtitle from the GridLayout.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#cccccc"
android:weightSum="6">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2.5"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTitleEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="My Title"
        android:textSize="32dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="You can enter some values"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/textSubTitleEdit"/>

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
            android:columnCount="10"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:useDefaultMargins="true">

            <TextView
                android:text="Name"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="0"/>

            <EditText
                android:ems="7"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:id="@+id/new_name"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="Label"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_column="0"/>

            <EditText
                android:ems="7"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:id="@+id/new_label"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:text="Put in a number"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                />

            <EditText
                android:ems="7"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:id="@+id/new_price"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:text="Another number"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_row="5" />

            <EditText
                android:ems="7"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:id="@+id/new_offset"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_row="5"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seek_offset"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.SeekBar"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="6"
                android:max="20"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="Comment"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_row="7"
                android:layout_column="0" />

            <EditText
                android:ems="7"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:id="@+id/new_comment"
                android:layout_row="7"
                android:layout_column="1" />

        </GridLayout>

</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/new_cancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity=""
                android:background="#aaaaaa"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/new_ok"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#dddddd"
                android:text="Ok"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```